# how can i choose a particular process to run in perl

Tags: perl, network-programming

Is there a command or function that i can create to choose to run anyone of these nmap scans that i desire instead of how my code runs now, which is the first ip address scanning and the rest follow?

Here is my code:

```
(`nmap -v -r 99.xxx.xxx -p 1-200`);
(`nmap -v -r 98.xxx.xxx -p 1-200`);
(`nmap -v -r 96.xxx.xxx -p 1-200`);
```

Comment: Insufficient data for meaningful answer.  How should it choose which one to run or whether to run one of them at all?  What do you mean by "instead of" how you code runs now?  How *does* your code run now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `@ARGV`:

```
system("nmap -v -r $ARGV[0] -p 1-200");
```

And call your script with the address in the CLI argument, such as `perl foo.pl 99.1.1.1`

Comment: And if not `$ARGV[0]`, then at least some variable.  However, the code should also assign the results to a string variable.  With the backticks as shown (in Perl), the output is captured and thrown away.  So: `my $scan = qx(nmap -v -r $ip_address -p 1-200);`.

Comment: I see you added the back-ticks to the question - was there a reason for that?  It might be that it is just a case of 'send output to stdout`, in which case, `system` might be a better choice, or something roughly equivalent.

Comment: I just copied the OP's code verbatim, other than adding `@ARGV`... thank you for catching the `system()` optimization